# Python string comparison smallest/largest str

Tags: python, string

I have a list of string of dates. For example,

```
x = ['2000-01-01', '2001-01-01', '2002-01-01']
```

I would like to filter these strings with optional lower and upper bounds. I can achieve it using if statements. For example,

```
def filter_str(x, lower_bound = '', upper_bound = ''):
    if lower_bound:
        x = [y for y in x if y > lower_bound]
    if upper_bound:
        x = [y for y in x if y < upper_bound]
    return x
```

I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way to do this?

---

I've found out that empty string (`''`) is smaller than any non-empty string. Is there a string that's larger than every non-empty string?

This way, I can simplify `filter_str` to

```
def filter_str(x, lower_bound = '', upper_bound = LARGEST_STR):
    return [y for y in x if y > lower_bound and y < upper_bound]
```

For my case, all the strings in the list starts with a number, so I guess `'a'` is larger than any string from my list. But if my list is more general with any kind of string, is there a largest string?

Thanks!

Comment: Your input is a list of string, however they represent dates. You should preferably use the datetime library included in Python.

Comment: Is there a largest/smallest date in datetime? That may work. I'm working with strings because I don't see the need to convert to datetime. The only thing I'm doing is comparison and that works ok in this string format.

Comment: Year 10k problems aside, you could use `9999-99-99`.

Comment: smallest time is usually `1970-01-01`

Comment: `1970-01-01` is not the smallest representable datetime object, it is simply the `0` unix time. It is perfectly valid to enter a datetime object like this: `datetime.datetime(1960,1,1)` You just can't use the `timestamp()` method on datetime objects before 1970.

Comment: If your input is really going to be dates then @chepner 's comment is spot on. No need for datetimes.

Comment: Got it. That works! But do you know if python has the concept of largest string like it has in terms of integer?

Comment: @Tim Yes, it does; there's no largest integer, and there's no largest string.

Comment: Hmmm, why would you not use a datetime object to compare dates? Seems harmful.

Comment: It would certainly be more robust to convert all the list elements to datetime objects and use the built in comparison methods of those objects than relying on the input being decent. The [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library may be useful here as it tries to "guess" at date formats rather than requiring a specific format, but it's therefore less-deterministic.

Comment: I see. Good point. Wasn't thinking of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in `filter` function treats `None` as a "function" that always returns `True`.

```
from functors import partial
from operators import lt, gt

def filter_dates(x, lower_bound=None, upper_bound=None):
    lb = None if lower_bound is None else partial(lt, lower_bound)
    ub = None if upper_bound is None else partial(gt, upper_bound)

    return filter(lb, filter(ub, x))
```

(Note that this will work with strings or `date` objects; just pass the lower and upper bounds of the appropriate type.)

Comment: Interesting idea!

Answer (score 1):

You could let your **default** input be dates far away, consider this:

```
import datetime

x = ['2000-01-01', '2001-01-01', '2002-01-01']
datefmt = "%Y-%m-%d" # The dateformat used to parse the dates

# This code can live for 180+ years, YAY! (2019-02-26)
def filter_str(x, lower_bound='1900-01-01', upper_bound='2199-12-31'):

  lb = datetime.datetime.strptime(lower_bound, datefmt)
  ub = datetime.datetime.strptime(upper_bound, datefmt)

  return [y for y in x if lb < datetime.datetime.strptime(y, datefmt) < ub]

out = filter_str(x, lower_bound='2000-02-01', upper_bound='2003-01-01')
print(out)
```

Returns:

```
['2001-01-01', '2002-01-01']
```

> NOTE: This code could use some input check that you are passing valid dates.

Comment: Thanks! How would you go about validating the input? strptime would raise Error if the format is not correct. Is that not enought?

Comment: @Tim It is certainly enough. Your code would simply break at that point. Depends where you want to "deploy" the code.

Comment: I see. You are saying there could be other ways of handling the input to make it smoother rather than breaking?

Comment: @Tim I'm saying that if there is some user input there can be errors and I just wanted to note that there were no error-handlers in the code I just wrote.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!